# Angular 4's equivalent to JQuery.load()

Tags: angular

I have use case where I am attempting to replicate JQuery.load() in Angular 4.  It appears pre-Angular 2 had the ng-include option but that functionality does not work in Angular 2/4 from what I attempted to do and what I've read. Does Angular 4 have an equivalent functionality to JQuery.load()? Thanks.

Comment: If it's ajax .load(), use the Http class from @angular/http.

Comment: @DanielH.J. I'll give this a shot. Thanks.

Comment: @DanielH.J. This doesn't appear to be what I am looking for. This is what I am trying to replicate http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Daniel is correct. You would use the HTTP class to make an api call to retrieve the data

Comment: you can't approach an angular app with a jquery mindset.  You shouldn't be trying to retrieve html fragments anymore, you should be retrieving json and writing your templates in angular to be populated with that json. If you absolutely MUST be retrieving HTML fragments, then you just use the http service to load fetch the HTML and then use the dom sanitizer to put it on the page.

Comment: @DavidAguirre I am trying to utilize the "Load Page Fragment" functionality so I can pull in a div from another page within my Angular 4 app.

$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html #container" );

I don't see that functionality in the Http class documentation. Am I looking at the right documentation?

https://angular.io/api/http/Http

Comment: If the template already exists then just make it into an angular component and reuse it, as I stated, you NEED to get out of the jquery mindset and embrace the angular way if you want to make an angular app.

Comment: @user1013651 you are talking about retrieving data from another component. You need to look in shared services, observables, and behavior subjects.

Comment: @bryan60 Bare with me I'm only been in the angular world for about 6 months. What I am attempting to prototype is pull in a page fragment from another page so I can hide it's iframe element's src attribute. It appeared that JQuery.load() method could achieve this so I am looking for similar functionality in Angular 4. Do you know of a feature in angular 4 that can achieve this?

Comment: there isn't one because angular and jquery are completely different paradigms.  there is never a need to have such a function in an angular.  Your app is no longer composed of "pages" and "framgnets". it's all just components and services now.

Comment: @bryan60 I see. I'll try to figure something out with components. Thanks.

Comment: do you want javascript to execute only once when your actual 1 page app loads? or do you want javascript to execute when you display different "pages" of you angular app?

Comment: If you absolutely must, you can also try to import jQuery as a class from the library file, but then that defeats the purpose of using Angular as a framework. The advantage of jQuery is you can manipulate DOM any way you like, but it becomes exponentially harder to maintain as your site grows. Angular stems from the separation of concerns in programming, so you don't manipulate, but simply initialize a view component when you need it, and destroy it when finished.